# Sitecore, with GlassMapper not returning known item

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

Problem two of my Sitecore saga:  There is a call similar to this:

```
var item = sitecoreService.GetItem<KnownMappedObject>(knownId)
```

This code works in production, and in most other cases the code is working correctly, however I navigate to a page and this line **item** is null.

The knownId is correct, e.g it exists in the database, but its coming back as null.  I have pulled the databases from production locally to ensure everything is correct, and I have even attempted to ensure the configuration is correct.

Are there any other rules for this method that would make it return null, even if the item exists?

*Edit*
Item is in the database, not sure how to see what language it is associated to though.  The content is not multi lingual.

*Edit 2*
So, the item is getting returned from the DB, and the language in the DB suggests EN.  However when we step through the code (in sitecore) it bails out on an item where it checks the Item.Version == 0.  Only way to get around that is with the *VersionDisabler*.  I don't think this is the answer as it is not present in production.

Also, the "Language" object that is being passed in has the name of the current page?? I would have thought it to be "en" or something like that??

Thanks,
James

Comment: Does he item exist in the web database? In the correct language?

Comment: Is your concrete type missing any key mapping attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Sitecore was taking the first part of the URL in this case as the language, and thus filtering the versions of the item by an unknown language.

Resulting in the item not being returned (As no language versions existed!)

There is a setting:

```
<setting name="Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage" value="false"/>
```

Which needs to be false to prevent this from happening.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

Typically reasons are:

- no context language version (is single language defined here default 'en'?)

- no read access for current user (try to wrap with SecurityDisabler)

Comment: Please try to add a line like `var rawItem = sitecoreService.GetItem<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item>(knownId)` to retrieve regular sitecore item - if it will return correct item then problem is in casting to your model. If it is still null - try `Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(id)`. Which database uses your sitecoreService?

Comment: It bails before the casting of the model.  It has somerhing to do with having no versions of content.  E.g the SiteCore.Data.Items.Item object has a .Versions property and it is empty.